# top offset on page load coming from different pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am implementing a joomla!3-based website where the main content is "onepage" and the navigation works using `scrollTop` and a fixed menu. The website also features some other pages that share the same menu.
I have a problem with the `scrollTop` `offset` when coming back from a different page to the homepage. The page loads at the correct id, according to the hashed url, but I can't figure out how to add the offset.
I hope I have well explained my problem.
Basically my code is:

```
... 
   <div class="navbar-collapse">
      <ul>
        <li class="item-101 current active"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
        <li class="item-105"><a href="#claim" >what we do</a></li>
        <li class="item-106"><a href="#wwa" >who we are</a></li>
        <li class="item-107"><a href="#port" >portfolio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div id="claim"></div>
      <div id="wwa"></div>
      <div id="port"></div>
    </div>
    ...
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

          $(".navbar-collapse ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

               target = this.hash;
               e.preventDefault();

               $('html, body').animate({
                   scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top -149
                   }, 300, function(){
                   window.location.hash = target;
               });

          });

        });
      </script>
      ...
```

The "portfolio" section opens projects in new pages. I encounter the problem I'm trying to solve getting back to the homepage from a project. The homepage loads correctly and skips directly to the right section if wanted, but I can't set an offset, so part of the section is hidden under the navigation menu.
Hope it's clearer now. I've read some questions on SO, but can't make the solutions suitable for my need...thanks again

Comment: can you post some HTML markup as well, also jsfiddle or URL of project may be helpful

Comment: Sorry If I was unclear. I edited with some markup.